# Associate url shortcut file to open with an Internet explorer - WIN 10 PRO

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts

When you drag the url bar from an internet explorer bar to a Windows folder, it creates a shortcut file. When double clicking that file, it should open that internet page in your default internet browser. This happens because by default, the filetype "url shortcut" is associated with your default browser in the registry.

I have here a file with a filetype of "url shortcut":

[image]

My issue is that when I double click a url shortcut filetype, instead of opening an internet browser page, it opens the print dialog:

[image]

Only if I DRAG the file onto an Internet browser page - will it open the linked shortcut in the browser.

I have tried to reset all file associations back to default but that didn't help.
In my Windows 10, in the "Choose default apps by file type" I have "Internet Shortcut (.url)" SET to open with "Internet Browser" (with no option to choose the browser, even though CHROME is set as my default browser) but for some reason, instead of opening them in chrome, it opens the print dialog.

[image]

Can someone help with this?

UPDATE:

After playing around with registry keys, I was able to get Windows to ask me what program I wanted to always open this type of file with. If I choose "Internet Browser" it works once but if I double click it again, it will again start to open the print dialog.

But if I choose "Chrome" - it always opens in Chrome BUT only shows the shortcut link as text like so:

[image]

Comment: Relevant, especially to @goza's answer below: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/windows-internet-browser.html

Answer (score 5):

Have exactly the same issue. Appeared suddenly.

Solved it by deleting with tool RegEdit the **`LegacyDisable`** key in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IE.AssocFile.URL\Shell\Open
```

[image]

Comment: @Blackwood, I posted an answer. Can you upvote my Answer again?

Comment: As you have edited your post to include an answer, I have deleted my comment. It wasn't me that downvoted your post.

Comment: @Tom, I upvoted your answer only because I think that it's a valid suggestion, especially if it worked for you. But I can't mark it as solved as it didn't help me. I temporarily am using a chrome extension "URL Handler" which handles .url files if they open on in Chrome as plain text.

Comment: This works for me: Windows 10 Pro & Google Chrome 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: On Win11 23H2 I can not delete the key, even as the system admin getting the message "Unable to delete all specified values."

Answer (score 1):

Do not associate `.url` directly with an internet browser but with 
the `InternetShortcut`

```
assoc .url  
.url=**InternetShortcut**
```

The InternetShortcut shell is realized by statement:

`"C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" "C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll",OpenURL file.url`

The shell extracts the real `url` from the given `file.url` and passes it to the default internet browser e.g. chrome:

Shortly you have to set the association:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ASSOC .url=InternetShortcut
```

And the registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe\" "C:\\Windows\\System32\\ieframe.dll\",OpenURL %l"
```

Comment: I checked and my reg string is already set to that. So for now, I just have to use the .URL Handler addon

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.

Comment: How were you able to work out (or maybe "where were you able to find") the rundll32 command-line used?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (for myself, at least):

I simply switched the default browser in Default Apps (System Settings). It was Firefox. After the first switch, it worked with all browsers. Maybe an issue in the registry, and the key got rewritten by switching ...

[image]